# How to apply a path planning algorithm in UWSim

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pathplanning, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone knows about how to develop your code on the platform of UWSim?I want to test my path planning algorithm in UWSim,like planning a pratical path from a start point to a goal position with obstacle avoidance,but I have no idea where to start.How should I configure the map or mark the obstacle.How to generate the trajectory and virualize it in UWSim.These are confusing issues because UWSim has no API at all.So I am here for someone who has relavent experience in using UWSim.Just tell me the idea of how to do it and thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412908/how-to-apply-a-path-planning-algorithm-in-uwsim/) by [marvelousluke](https://answers.ros.org/users/121802/marvelousluke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2023-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

UWSim is more of a nice renderer that takes either your robot current pose or cmd_vel as an input.

In order to do path planning you have to get a representation of the robot and its surrounding environment in a dedicated planner.
How you fill this environment with information is up to you. UWSim can publish 3D point clouds but you could just use the ground truth when testing the planner itself.

To my point of view the resulting trajectory should be visualized in RViz and not UWSim.

---

Originally posted by [Olivier Kermorgant](https://answers.ros.org/users/11856/olivier-kermorgant/) with karma: 280 on 2023-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marvelousluke](https://answers.ros.org/users/121802/marvelousluke/) on 2023-02-28**:
Thank you sir for your answer! I know RViz should do but I am looking for a way to generate some trajectory curve in UWSim which g500 can follow.(without considering control algorithm for now)
Question is that there is not much information about UWSim usage.So sir,could you please advise me how to learn it?

**Comment by [marvelousluke](https://answers.ros.org/users/121802/marvelousluke/) on 2023-03-08**:
Hey I am back to Rviz now.And I came up with a new question here[link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/413194/could-gmapping-pkg-work-in-uwsim/) hopefully you could give me a little advice.Thanks!